# Keeping buttons in place when using .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

Not sure if this is because I'm new to meteor or if I am making an error in my syntax with my HTML or jQuery. Ideally I would like the whole grid to stay in place when a button is clicked. For example if you clicked the button in the middle of the grid there would be a empty spot where that button was before. My question is, **why is it that when I click a button the button disappears but moves the whole grid and what do I do to fix this?**

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>bubblepopper</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>{{> grid}}</center>

</body>
<template name ="grid">
  <div id="container">
    {{#each buttons}}
      <button class="button" type="button"></button>
    {{/each}}
  </div>

</template>
```

JS:

```
Buttons = new Meteor.Collection("buttons");
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  player = prompt("What is your name?")

  Template.grid.buttons = function () {
   }
   Template.grid.buttons = function () {
     var list = [];
     for(var i=1; i<=64; i++){
       list.push({value: i});
    }
   return list;
};

Template.grid.events({
  'click .button': function(ev) {
    $(ev.target).hide()
  }
});

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.hide()` works by adding the style `display: none` to the element. This removes the space used by the element in the rendered page.

If you want to make something invisible but keep its space on the page, use the `visibility` style:

```
$(ev.target).css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

To restore it, set the visibility to `visible`.